# Approve submitted data by admin in php

Tags: php

There is registration form in which country field is there.if user's country is not in drop down list. user can select other at that time display one textbox and user enter their country in textbox.after submit country by user .how to approve the requested country and publish in country drop down list in php.

**config.php**

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$con)
{
    die("Could not connect".mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("RateMyProfessor",$con);

?>
```

**Demo.php**

```
 <?php 

include ("config.php");
$query = "select * from user_details where is_approved='0'";

$result=mysql_query($query);

$i = 1; //counter for the checkboxes so that each has a unique name
echo "<form action='process.php' method='post'>"; //form started here
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>UserId</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Country </th>
<th>Update</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['UserId'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Email'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Country'] . "</td>";

  echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='check[$i]' value='".$row['UserId']."'/>";   
  echo "</tr>";
  $i++;
  }
echo "</table>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='approve' value='approve'/>";
echo "</form>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

**process.php**

```
<?php
include_once("config.php");
if(isset($_POST['approve']))
{
        if(isset($_POST['check']))
        {
                    foreach ($_POST['check'] as $value){
                        echo $value;
                        $sql = "update user_details set is_approved ='1' where UserId = '$value'"; 

                        mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

                    }
        }
}
?>
```

when admin is approve country from admin side country is copy on country table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert a new record in country table at the time of approval
for e.g.

```
<?php
include_once("config.php");
if(isset($_POST['approve']))
{
        if(isset($_POST['check']))
        {
                    foreach ($_POST['check'] as $value){
                        echo $value;
                        $sql = "update user_details set is_approved ='1' where UserId = '$value'"; 

                        mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

                        $sql = "select other_country from user_details where UserId = '$value'"; 

                        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());


                         if($Other_country_name = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                         {
                              $Other_country_name = $Other_country_name['other_country'];
                         }


                        $sql = "insert into country_table set name = '$Other_country_name'";

                        mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

                    }
        }
}
?>
```

I have not implemented conditions. please do it by yourself